# Home network extension

Tags: home-networking

I have a very standard home network set up. A single ISP with a modem and a wireless router.

A problem I have is that the wireless range of the router isn't great.

I have a cat6 Ethernet cable running to another room. I would like to be able to connect that cable to some other device (switch, another router, repeater?) so that I have improved wireless range within that room and also the option to connect other wired devices into the device. I also want this to be the same network, so that wireless devices would connect to either using the same security settings.

What is the correct device I should be using for this? Are there any special configurations I would need to carry out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just need another wireless router. Connect it to the LAN pot of your first router at one end, and the other end to the LAN of your second router. Then set the second router to bridge mode (turn off NAT and DHCP services so that your main router is the only one handling these) and make your SSID, Security, and password the same. You may want to set different wireless channels on both routers to ensure both wireless signals don't interfere with each other, but with these steps, your devices should connect to whichever router is giving it the best signal at a given place seamlessly. Any router should work as long as you can do these required tasks on it.